# Wi-Fi point my shed - I don't know what to buy

Tags: wireless-networking, cable, repeater

I have just had fibre installed; I have a Wi-Fi repeater extending the Wi-Fi but my shed is too far away to benefit.

I used to have a cable running from my 4G box to my shed and this worked fine, but now I would like to use the cable to run from the repeater to the shed and have Wi-Fi in the shed (at the moment I would have to plug the cable into my laptop in the shed and use my laptop as a hot spot).

Please can anyone tell me what I need to buy for the shed that would plug into the cable and give me Wi-Fi in the shed - I really hope this makes sense - I live in France and some of the names of things might be different.

UPDATE
Thanks everyone for your advise, I have added a link to an image (I hope) showing the layout.
The Fibre comes into an Orange Livebox, the garage has a Repeteur WIFI 6 UP supplied by Orange (I don't know if this is a repeater or extender) this is installed on the door closest to the house and gives the garage wifi, there is a CAT 6 cable going from the Repeteur to the shed and this give me internet when I plug my laptop in but I'd rather plug it into a access point so I have wifi in the shed.

Thank you for all your help - I'm off to Am**** UK to look for a wifi access point :-)

[image: Layout] - link should show my layout

Comment: You would need a [wireless access point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_access_point) (A.K.A. Wifi access point as you want it to use Wi-Fi). You would plug the existing cable into the access point, and it will need mains power unless you have PoE.

Comment: Does the repeater have an Ethernet/network port and does plugging in a PC directly there work?

Comment: Is the new router where the old 4G box was,, and if so do you still have the cable running from where the router is to the shed?

Comment: If you are running a cable from your main networking equipment to the shed.  I would just purchase a router and connect to it's LAN port.

Comment: Not sure you knew this but repeaters are an abomination to network performance (like by 1/2).  You say "repeater extending" which makes me wonder if this is a repeater or extender (big difference).  Repeaters suck but are cheap and work for some situations.  Extenders don't suck but are basically routers that are smart enough to extend access to another wifi network via bridge.  You might want to think about this and an extender might very will fix your speed AND what you are talking about here.

Comment: @Ramhound It's probably worth writing *a router with Wi-Fi* rather than just a router, seeing as the OP wants Wi-Fi at the shed and they are asking for the name of a suitable device.

Comment: @AndrewMorton - I don't know very many routers on the market which don't include WiFi.  I know many switches that don't include WiFi.  I used the term `router` for a specific reason.

Comment: The word router or (routeur) describe the same device in my experience. I looked through 5 pages of results on Amazon and was unable to find any that did not include WiFi functionality.

Comment: No image visible :(  (Also, be aware that your edit makes this post close to off-topic as (a) Its become a shopping recommendation and (b) its not English - which is off topic here because it frustrates stupid monoglots like me).  When I go to your link its not clear what product it is.  There is a brief description of what looks like a repeater at the top, but most of the page is about a router. While routers can be configured to do what you want (per my post) the device you are looking for is an AP (Access Point/point d'accès)

Comment: Hi Davidgo, Sorry I'll remove the link.  It is one of my  problems, I am in France so am looking for a product I can buy in France but I can't work out which is a wireless access point.  I think I'll have to order one from UK.  PS - my french isn't great so I rely on Google Translate and it is a bit unreliable with things like this.  Thank you for your help :-)

Comment: Most wireless routers will work as access points as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comments you can use an AP (access point)

An AP will likely be easier to configure and will give you more direct to other parts of your network (eg device discovery) and easier/more seemless roaming between locations

If you are using a router you will want to change its internal IP range so as not to conflict with the IP range of the main router.

Its worth bearing in mind its usually practical to "convert" a router to behave like an AP - disable DHCP and don't use the WAN port - ie connect the cable into a LAN port.

When configuring the router or AP, use the same WIFI settings as the main network to fascilitate roaming.  You may want to use a different channel though (depending on how far away the devices are this may or may not make a performance difference.

Comment: Thanks everyone for all your help - I have updated my original question with more information - I have been out of the IT business for nearly 20 years and I am floundering :-)

Comment: @KarenFrance - since this worked, the protocol is to tick the answer as the correct answer.